# at least 3 checkboxes in a group must be checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation to validate a form for building a custom assessment.   There are multiple sections on the form one of them is personality.  The personality section is comprised of 10 different dimensions. If the user opts to use the personality section they can opt to use all or some of the dimensions in the section.  At minimum they must select at least 3 of the dimensions.

I am using jQuery Validate plugin along with its additional-methods file to use the `require_from_group` validation method

when i test this the required part works but it is not making them select the minimum of 3 of the dimensions that are required

here is the form html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sections" value="Personality" id="Personality" onClick="displayPersonality(this.form)" /> <label for="Personality">Personality -- cost varies by number of dimensions chosen</label>
    <div id="persDimensions" class="radio-group" style="display:none">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Energy" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Energy" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Energy">Energy</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Flexibility" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Flexibility" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Flexibility">Flexibility</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Organization" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Organization" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Organization">Organization</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Communication" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Communication" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Communication">Communication</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Development" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Development" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Development">Emotional Development</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Assertiveness" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Assertiveness" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Assertiveness">Assertiveness</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Competitiveness" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Competitieness" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Competitieness">Competitieness</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Toughness" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Toughness" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Toughness">Mental Toughness</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Questioning" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Questioning" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Questioning">Questioning/Probing</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Motivation" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Motivation" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Motivation">Motivation</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="PersonalityDimension" value="Distortion" onclick="CountDims(this.form)" id="Distortion" class="pick-three" /> <label for="Distortion">Distortion</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="checkbox" name="Equivocation" value="1" id="Equivocation" /> <label for="Equivocation">Equivocation</label></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my validation code

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        PersonalityDimension:{
            require_from_group: function(element){
                if($('#Personality').is(':checked')){
                    return [3,".pick-three"] ;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

any ideas why it is not requiring 3 of the checkboxes be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use the same `name` attribute on a group of radio or checkbox elements, just as you've done.  However, the `require_from_group` method is looking for elements with different names, and the rule would be applied three unique times.  You would use it on three completely different input elements, not three checkboxes within the same group.

It's a moot point, as the `require_from_group` was not created for your type of situation.  The solution is to simply use the `minlength` rule to mandate a minimum number of checkboxes.

```
<form id="myform">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" />
    </div>
    ....
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        foo: {  // name of my checkbox group
            required: true,  // at least one checkbox with this alone
            minlength: 3  // at least how many must be checked?
        }
    },
    messages: {
        foo: {
            minlength: "check at least {0}" // {0} automatically inserts parameter value
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/gmvck6oe/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/gmvck6oe/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.